# create Oracle db DBA Role with read only priviliges

Tags: oracle

I'm wondering if there's a way to set up a user with dba-like read-only privileges.
In my use-case, I'm trying to fetch some data from of schema from SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS table.
I'm using this statements to create my user:

```
CREATE USER bbb IDENTIFIED BY bbb;
/
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO bbb;
/
grant select any table to bbb WITH ADMIN OPTION;
/
grant select on SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS to bbb;
```

when I try to run the following statement to fetch data of HR schema:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS a WHERE a.OWNER = 'HR'  ORDER BY SEQUENCE;
```

I get nothing. If I set my user with DBA role or IMP_FULL_DATABASE role, i manage to get this data but then my user has privileges I don't want him to have.

Comment: [`ALL_ARGUMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-1F535054-CABC-4321-AA2F-151DA726A2D7.htm) lists the arguments of the functions and procedures that are accessible to the current user. For BBB to be able to access all of them you would need to grant `execute any procedure`, or possibly `debug any procedure`, not `select any table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privilege `SELECT ANY TABLE` does not include dictionary views. Run

```
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO bbb;
```

in order to grant full read access.

Comment: And use dba_arguments instead of all_arguments.

Comment: ALL_ views go by privs - and will be slower. DBA_ views show EVERYTHING.

Comment: the combination of select any dictionary and use of dba_arguments seems to do the trick!
thanks.